# Can't add an image to html template in Go

Tags: html, eclipse, go, goclipse

First of all, I created an HTML file using Notepad ++ with this code:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td><img src="images/test.jpg" border=3 height=100 width=300 /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

When I open this file it works fine, it shows me the table and the image inside the cell.

Then, in my Go Project inside Eclipse I created an HTML file with the same code and try to run but it didn't work, it didn't show the image.

So, I tried to put the image in the same folder as the HTML file and didn't work again.

Both are in the folder: tmpl

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td><img src="test.jpg" border=3 height=100 width=300 /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Problem:**

rootHandler: Could not forward request for /tmpl/teste.jpg any further.

**Go Code:**

```
// * /
func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        homeHandler(w, r)
    } else {
        log.Printf("rootHandler: Could not forward request for %s any further.", r.RequestURI)

        errNotFound(w, r)
    }
}
```

Comment: No code --> no help.

Comment: @Volker I posted the code. Take a look please.

Comment: Could you please submit the solution as answer to your question - it will help other users by indicating that the problem is solved. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Add a FileServer to the project:

```
m.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("images/"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder. Give it any name, here I've used "image". Put all images in this folder. Then, in your main function, add this line:

```
http.Handle("/image/", http.StripPrefix("/image", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./image"))))
```

Comment: Create a folder give any name I am giving as image and put all images in the same folder only

and in you main function add this line :-

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).